# React Native Fetch data from API - BUT not render in flat list, just single time

Tags: reactjs, fetch, native

Can anyone help, i find only with render in Flatlist like in example, BUT i need without Flatlist

```
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
```

import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

```
export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.map((item, id) => (<Text key={id}>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>)
```